# How to Manipulate React Navigation Stack Order

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Description: I am using React Navigation and currently have the following stack order:

- /explore-home
- InitialScreen

Suppose I am on the /explore-home screen, and I navigate to /my-application. In this scenario, I insert another screen, say /my-favorite, below /my-application.

Desired stack order:

- /my-application
- /explore-home
- initialScreen

I want to achieve the following manipulation:

- /my-application
- **(+) /my-favorite**
- /explore-home
- InitialScreen

Specifically, when I am on /my-application and press the back button, I want to navigate back to /my-favorite without visiting /my-favorite

How can I achieve this using React Navigation? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!